# What is the recource pack lang for Swedish?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

If you make a resource pack, you probably know that the lang folder contains an "en_us.json", but that is for English, I'm Swedish, and I want to replace item names without switching to the English language.

Does anyone know the JSON name for Swedish, is it like "se.json"?
Thanks!

Comment: It's probably "`sv_se`". They are all listed in `.minecraft/assets/indexes/<version>.json`.

Comment: Thank you! but is there any way to download or get the Swedish version of the sv_se.json, it will take forever to replace all the item names.

Comment: What do you mean with "Swedish version"? Those are the Swedish translations.

Comment: to build on what Fabian said, ``sv_se.json`` is the same in functionality as ``en_us.json``. where ``en_us.json`` handles English, ``sv_se.json`` handled Swedish. i just am confused why you need it for a resource pack? from my understanding you can't change an item's name through there.